# Target pages on my site are getting deindexed by google

Tags: html, seo, meta, noindex

every target page we have built links to is fetting deindexed

could it be this tag (although i thought it was always there)

or is it the links im building? This site i am talking about is 1800lawfirm.com

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
```

Comment: Yes. That tag tells the search engine not to index the page...

Answer (score 0):

The robots tag with a noindex directive in it is telling search engines **not to include** that page in the index.  You should remove the robots tag to allow the pages to rank.

Comment: You probably mean "noindex" instead of "nofollow".